# Failure to access ubuntu respositories unless vpn installed first

Tags: system-installation

A default install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 can connect to the internet via Firefox but fails to connect to any repositories.  Neither does Software Update or via CLI unless a VPN is installed and active.  Same outcome on 2 different machines.  Ubuntu was installed by thumb drive. My vpn service is through Expressvpn.

Both mobo's have LANs built in as well as wireless connectivity.  I utilize the LAN ports.  To be clear; both machines had internet access prior to vpn installation through Firefox.  Repository access denied through Firefox, CLI or Software update until the vpn was activated.  I was able to download and activate Expressvpn through their website which was how I discovered default repository access repaired once it was activated.  Expressvpn was installed through the terminal using dpkg -i .

It's not a problem as I utilize a vpn, but why would a default install fail a hard wire connection to the repositories?

My system:  Netgear cable-modem set to pass-through to Mikrotik router (default settings) to Linksys switch to LAN

scott@xHDX:~$ expressvpn disconnect
Disconnected.

scott@xHDX:~$ ping google.com
ping google.com
PING google.com (142.251.33.46) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from dfw28s31-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.33.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=15.6 ms

64 bytes from dfw28s31-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.33.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=18.1 ms

64 bytes from dfw28s31-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.33.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=12.5 ms

64 bytes from dfw28s31-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.33.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=118 time=13.4 ms

scott@xHDX:~$ sudo apt update
0% [Connecting to kazooie.canonical.com (91.189.91.39)] [Waiting for headers]

Comment: Home machine, no proxy or enterprise/school network

Comment: The only adjustments to the Mikrotik were upgrading firmware to their latest and greatest, and opening some ports.  I did change the IP from their default 88.1 to 1.1, but really, that's it.  I use expressvpn which connect to somewhere in TX.  I wish I could tell you more but to quote Bones, dammit, man, I'm a doctor, not a computer programmer! I do suspect it's some default setting on the Mikrotik..

Comment: Please [edit] your quiestion and add all requested information or clarification there instead of using comments for this purpose. Can you access the software repositories using Firefox? I suggest to use a network sniffer (Wireshark, tcpdump) to find out what's different between the network connections of Firefox and software updater.

Comment: Are you using Proton VPN?

Comment: Can you connect to the Ubuntu repositories using a web browser? (The URLs are in your /etc/apt/sources.list).

Comment: copied/pasted each repository URL into Firefox and only would connect with VPN activation

Comment: Do you have "kill switch" enabled in the Express VPN config? If so, disable the "kill switch".

Comment: There is a kill switch which I deactivated.   I am wondering if there some kind of HTTP HTTPS security protocol in the mikrotik that could be the problem?

Comment: Can you paste the output of e.g. `sudo apt update` without VPN activated, and the result of `ping -6 google.com`? I'm guessing you have IPv6 incorrectly configured, and your VPN software effectively disables IPv6.

Comment: ping -6 google.com wouldn't connect with or without vpn connected. ping google.com did connect without the vpn.  I put the results in the question